# MPI calloc Causes Segmentation Fault

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, mpi

I wrote a program to find sum of array elements by MPI. Both root and workers finds the sum of a portion and workers sends partial sums to root at the end. When I try with a static sized array there isn't any problem. But it gives segmentation fault if I use calloc. The source code is given below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#define tag1 1 /* send from root to workers */
#define tag2 2 /* send from workers to root */
#define root 0
#define n_data 12

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{ 
    int total_sum, partial_sum;
    int my_id, i, n_procs, n_portion;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Status status;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_id);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &n_procs);
    n_portion=n_data/n_procs;

    int *array = (int *)calloc(n_data, sizeof(int));
    int *local  = (int *)calloc(n_portion, sizeof(int));

    if(my_id == root) { 

        /* initialize array */
        for(i = 0; i < n_data; i++) 
            array[i]=i;

        /* send a portion of the array to each worker */
        for(i= 1; i < n_procs; i++) 
            MPI_Send( &array[i*n_portion], n_portion, MPI_INT,i, tag1, MPI_COMM_WORLD); 

        /* calculate the sum of my portion */
        for(i = 0; i < n_portion; i++)
            total_sum += array[i];

        /* collect the partial sums from workers */
        for(i= 1; i < n_procs; i++) {
            MPI_Recv( &partial_sum, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_ANY_SOURCE,tag2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
            total_sum += partial_sum; 
        }

        printf("The total sum is: %d\n", total_sum);
    }
    else { /* I am a worker, receive data from root */

        MPI_Recv( &local, n_portion, MPI_INT, root, tag1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);

        /* Calculate the sum of my portion of the array */
        partial_sum = 0;
        for(i = 0; i < n_portion; i++)
            partial_sum += local[i];

        /* send my partial sum to the root */
        MPI_Send( &partial_sum, 1, MPI_INT, root, tag2, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }

    MPI_Finalize(); 
    return 0;
}
```

The error I took is:

```
-bash-4.1$ mpirun -np 3 distApprox
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpirun noticed that process rank 2 with PID 110834 on node levrek1 exited on signal 11 (Segmentation fault).
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: What is the value of `n_portion`?

Comment: did you tried to debug the code, on which line it gets segmentation fault?  well calloc returns the null pointer if it is not able to allocate the code.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I runned for 3 process and I have 12 elements in array. So `n_portion = 4`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg But, it should be like that. Because I am using root as a worker too. if `n_procs` is 2 root will calculate one half of the array and `worker1` will be calculate the other half.

Comment: @samet - Are you assuming it will be 4, or did you verify for a fact that it *is* 4?  Your code contains no error checking, which is why it is still not clear if the value is really 4.  All we have are calls to `calloc` with variables that we have no idea what they are.  How about hard-coding a `4` instead of using a variable?  If you did that, would you still have the issue?

Comment: You aren't checking the result of `calloc()`.  Maybe it's failing.

Comment: Side note: You forgot to initialize `total sum`. This fact leads me to believe that you need to turn up your warning level. Add `-wall` to your compiler command line (assuming you use `gcc`).

Comment: Thanks for comments. I am having trouble with mpi server for now. I will try all and give feedback in a few minutes.

Comment: Shouldn't it be just `local` instead of `&local` in the call of `MPI_Recv` ?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie The same problem exist when I hard-coded `n_portion` as 4. So, I initialized `total_sum = 0` as Klas pointed, and changed `&local` to `local` as Martin pointed. It works! Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say the problem lies in the MPI_Recv on the worker side.
You should use 'local' instead of '&local' as the buffer.
MPI expects the "initial adress of the receive buffer" [(see MPI standard)](http://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-3.1/mpi31-report/node50.htm#Node50),
which in the case of dynamic arrays is the array variable itself.

```
MPI_Recv( local, n_portion, MPI_INT, root, tag1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
```

You may also want to initialize 'total_sum' to 0 on root and then your code should run.

Edit: Just saw that Martin Zabel already pointed this out in the comments

Comment: Thanks! Perfect solution.